# Monitoring CLCirculerregion didStartMonitoring called,but didEnterRegion or didExitRegion never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, geofencing

I am creating an iOS app that need to monitor CLCirculerregions .I have set the coreLocationdelegate to my CLlocationManager object and added a region with 200m of radius . The problem is it only fire the didstartMonitoring method but didEnterRegion or didExitRegion methods never called.I have no idea to fix this issue .Code runs with no errors

Comment: can you give me a demon of Geofence? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running app on simulator. Then choose from simulator menu Debug->Location->CustomLocation and fill the coordinates of your CLCircularRegion. Now the -didEnterRegion method should be fired

Comment: I tried using simulator  but didn't work for me .further I implemented the location update delegate methods  then error occurred and looks it cant update CLLocationmanager on simulator ,thank you #ErmineSoft

Comment: solved ,  [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];  I added this line .it was my mistake and should have been added early .[locatonManage r requestWhenInUseAuthorization] is another option .Simply user have to give authorization to location manager to monitoring